# Is my understanding of expression statements correct?

Tags: javascript

I've read a lot of articles so I would appreciate not being linked to any and if you could help me understand the examples I give. The first touches on expression statements.

> [Wherever JavaScript expects a statement, you can also write an
> expression. Such a statement is called an expression statement.](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

1. `a = 5; a;`. Is what makes the second `a` a statement the semi-colon? The second `a` here is an expression statement. Is it because `a` resolves to a value?
2. However, if we'd have just wrote `a;` (without the `a = 5;`) would `a` be an invalid expression and if so, why? expressions have to return something so i) what's `a` returning and ii) what makes it invalid? Would it stop being an expression statement?

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218906/discussion-on-question-by-tonitone117-is-my-understanding-of-expression-statemen).

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is for statement *termination*, meaning it breaks them up. `a` is a valid expression for the value of `a`.

Notice that there are no errors here. There's no output because there wasn't one explicitly done.

```js
var a = 5;
a;
```

If you were to do `var a = 5 a` - that is syntactically incorrect, because it needs the semicolon.

If you are getting errors - you should declare `a` with `let`, `const` or `var`. Otherwise it will go to a global scope.

Comment: Maybe add an example where `a` is a function? Might be a little more obvious then :)