# Is this a valid example of a piece of code changing from a statement to an expression because the syntax of the code has changed?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f() {return 5;}; 
var x = f();
```

The execution of a function statement by itself (`f()`) is an [expression statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174636/is-my-understanding-of-expression-statements-correct). However, in the code snippet above (`var x = f();`), is the `f()` part of the code no longer an expression statement - and therefore just an expression - because statements can’t appear where expressions are expected?

Answer (score 2):

An expression is any statement (or part of the statement) that return some result. Whenever we call a function it is an expression because it returns a value. Even if the function body does not include any return statement, it returns `undefined` by default.

The statement `var x = f();` is not an expression because it returns no value. However, the left side `f()` is still an expression because it will return some value. `x = f()` is also an expression because it also returns some result. We can also verify that `x = f()` is an expression by putting this in `if` condition. However, that part `var` is not an expression, and putting it in `if` condition will throw an error.

I hope this clears your confusion. To answer this question I took little help from [here](https://medium.com/launch-school/javascript-expressions-and-statements-4d32ac9c0e74)